# Proving that the plane is nonempty

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Can you think of any way to prove from the Euclidean postulates that the plane is
nonempty, i.e., that points and lines exist?

Comment: Do the postulates not implicitly presuppose the existence of points and lines, in order to make statements about their properties?

Comment: Yes, they do. You are absolutely right.

Comment: In [Hilbert's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms) the existence of points and lines is explicitly postulated.  See axiom $3$ under Incidence.

Comment: @SeraPhim: I don't think that Euclid's postulates do presuppose the existence of points and lines, as they all have hypotheses about the points and lines involved.  The OP might like to see https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookVII/bookVII.html#guide for more remarks on postulates that are missing from Euclid. (And please don't read these omissions as indictments on ancient Greek mathematics.)